# When can I switch sup and functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a sequence of random variables $X_k$.

Under which conditions can I say that $$f\left(\sup_{j \le k} X_k\right) = \sup_{j \le k} f(X_k)$$?

Would having $\limsup X_k = \lim_{k \to \infty} \sup_{j \le k} X_k = \sup_{k} X_k$ change anything in this regard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the $X_k$ are identified as random variables, the randomness plays no role here. We could just think of $X_k$ as sequences of real numbers.

One general condition that would suffice would be for $f$ to be an increasing function; the condition $\limsup X_k=\sup X_k$ would not be needed here. And a converse holds, in that if $f(\sup X_k)=\sup f(X_k)$ for all possible sequences of $X_k$, then $f$ must be increasing: just let $X_k$ take on two distinct degenerate values $x$ and $y$ (e.g., $X_1=x$ and $X_i=y$ for $i\geq2$), where $x\leq y$; then $f(\sup X_k)=\sup f(X_k)$ says that $f(y)=\sup\{f(x),f(y)\}$, i.e., $f(x)\leq f(y)$, so $f$ is increasing.

Another condition that would suffice would be to require $X_k$ to be an increasing sequence and $f$ to be left-continuous.